# Slick Slider Center mode

Tags: slider

I wanted to have such a  [slider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MOcPi.png) and decided to use slick slider center mode. but it doesn't work at all. i'm a bit newbie and can't make heads or tails of it.
here is what I made. I studied many examples but couldn't debug my codes.
would be grateful if someone help me.

```js
$('.mainslider').slick({
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '60px',
  slidesToShow: 3,
  responsive: [{
      breakpoint: 768,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 3
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        arrows: false,
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '40px',
        slidesToShow: 1
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 70%;
    border: 2px solid #707070;
  border-radius: 50px;

}
.slide {
   width: auto;
    height: 600px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: bottom;    
    border-radius: 50px;
    border: 0px solid #707070;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainslider">
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://images.theconversation.com/files/295442/original/file-20191003-52796-1763ajl.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=900.0&fit=crop');"></div></div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://images.theconversation.com/files/295442/original/file-20191003-52796-1763ajl.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=900.0&fit=crop');"></div></div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://images.theconversation.com/files/295442/original/file-20191003-52796-1763ajl.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=900.0&fit=crop');"></div></div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://images.theconversation.com/files/295442/original/file-20191003-52796-1763ajl.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=900.0&fit=crop');"></div></div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://images.theconversation.com/files/295442/original/file-20191003-52796-1763ajl.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=900.0&fit=crop');"></div></div>
        <div class="wrapper"><div class="slide" style="background-image: url('https://images.theconversation.com/files/295442/original/file-20191003-52796-1763ajl.jpg?ixlib=rb-1.1.0&q=45&auto=format&w=1200&h=900.0&fit=crop');"></div></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I don't know where else you are testing your code.. but in the example you've given above, you haven't included jquery or slick slider which is why your snippet isn't working. I would suggest adding those via cdn first and see if that helps :-)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. but yes, I have CDN linked to my codes on the main files. nevertheless, it's not working. and as far as I'm using the slick sliders, just this particular model is broke. I have other sliders and carousels which work properly